# apps script how copy selected cells in row from sheet to target cells in row of other sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to google apps script. I have source sheet (Column A: No, B: Name, C: Sex, D: Age, E:Type, F: Salary, G: Status (value yes/no) and destination sheet (Column A: Name, B: Sex, C: Salary). If a column G value == yes in source sheet, I want to copy value of row in column name, sex, salary to the last row of destination sheet. Thanks everyone

I am stuck, I don't know how to start the code.

My Fake Data:

| No | Name | Sex | Age | Type | Salary | Status(yes/no) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A2 | B2 | C2 | D2 | E2 | F2 | yes |
| A3 | B3 | C3 | D3 | E3 | F3 | no |
| A4 | B4 | C4 | D4 | E4 | F4 | yes |
| A5 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5 | F5 | no |
| A6 | B6 | C6 | D6 | E6 | F6 | yes |
| A7 | B7 | C7 | D7 | E7 | F7 | no |
| A8 | B8 | C8 | D8 | E8 | F8 | yes |
| A9 | B9 | C9 | D9 | E9 | F9 | no |
| A10 | B10 | C10 | D10 | E10 | F10 | yes |

Output:

| Name | Sex | Phone | Email | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B2 | C2 | - | - | F2 |
| B4 | C4 | - | - | F4 |
| B6 | C6 | - | - | F6 |
| B8 | C8 | - | - | F8 |
| B10 | C10 | - | - | F10 |

Comment: See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This get's the data from the src sheet and filters out all of the no's and maps cols b,c and f to a,b,c and appends them into the des sheet

```
function myfunk01() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh = ss.getSheetByName("src");
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName("des");
  const sr = 2;
  const dvs = ssh.getRange(sr,1,ssh.getLastRow() - sr + 1,ssh.getLastColumn()).getValues().filter(([a,b,c,d,e,f,g]) => g == "yes").map(([a,b,c,d,e,f,g]) => [b,c,-,-,f]);
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1,1,dvs.length,dvs[0].length).setValues(dvs);
}
```

My Fake Data:

| No | Name | Sex | Age | Type | Salary | Status(yes/no) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A2 | B2 | C2 | D2 | E2 | F2 | yes |
| A3 | B3 | C3 | D3 | E3 | F3 | no |
| A4 | B4 | C4 | D4 | E4 | F4 | yes |
| A5 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5 | F5 | no |
| A6 | B6 | C6 | D6 | E6 | F6 | yes |
| A7 | B7 | C7 | D7 | E7 | F7 | no |
| A8 | B8 | C8 | D8 | E8 | F8 | yes |
| A9 | B9 | C9 | D9 | E9 | F9 | no |
| A10 | B10 | C10 | D10 | E10 | F10 | yes |

Output:

| Name | Sex | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B2 | C2 | F2 |
| B4 | C4 | F4 |
| B6 | C6 | F6 |
| B8 | C8 | F8 |
| B10 | C10 | F10 |

Comment: Hi @Cooper! thank a lot! It works! But what if the destination sheet have the same columns as source sheet (No Name Sex Age Type Salary Status(yes/no)), but I need only copy the row data in column (Name Sex Salary) of source sheet to the same column name in destination sheet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091/cooper  thank a lot! It works! But what if the destination sheet have the same columns as source sheet (No Name Sex Age Type Salary Status(yes/no)), but I need only copy the row data in column (Name Sex Salary) of source sheet to the same column name in destination sheet. Thanks in advance. – 
SK360 Kiry
 1 hour ago   Delete

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Please show me an example of how you want the output to look like.

Comment: Soucre sheet        
No Name Sex Age Type Salary Status  
A2 B2      C2 D2 E2             F2 Yes  
A3 B3         C3 D3 E3             F3 No  
A4 B4         C4 D4 E4             F4   
A5 B5         C5 D5 E5             F5   
A6 B6         C6 D6 E6             F6 Yes  
   
        
        
Destination Sheet        
No Name Sex Contact Addess Salary   
 B2         C2                     F2   
 B6         C6                            F6

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091/cooper Thanks. I just known how to use the table in stack. Please see my revised question above. Thank for your help